# jq - Selecting objects containing certain key

Tags: json, jq

Let's say I have this JSON file below:

```
{
  "team": {
    "money": 100,
  },
  "group": {
    "money": 200,
    "snack": true,
  }
}
```

I want to select the objects which has a "snack" key including its parent. The current command I'm using is:

```
jq '..|objects|select(has("snack"))' json
```

This however, does not include the parent, which in this case is "group". How do I select the parent of the selected object as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `..`, you could use `paths`.  That is, you'd select the paths that lead to the items of interest, and work from there.  So you'd start with:

```
paths(objects) as $p
| select(getpath($p)|has("snack"))
| $p
```

For the given input (after having been corrected), this would yield:

```
["group"]
```

So you might want to replace the `$p` in the last line by `$p[-1]`, but it's not altogether clear how useful that would be. More useful would be `getpath( $p[:-1] )`